# Is there a way to prioritize web services in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, scalability

The goal is having a way to guarantee a certain SLA (Service Level Agreement) for some of the web services to guarantee backend database uptime. Ideally this should be achieved with no specific code in the services but by controlling the underlying infrastructure/pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, at least as a partial solution, proper isolation on the IIS level would be a good idea.  A specific application pool for the "high availability" web service, at MINIMUM would be a requirement in my book.